# SQL Server Database connection Error : "No statement handle available" Error: "

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qsqlquery

I am trying to connect SQL Server database. Here is my code:

```
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery, QSqlQueryModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableView, QApplication
import sys

SERVER = '192.19.45.11:1433'
DATABASE = 'insightAccounts'
USERNAME = 'Admin'
PASSWORD = '******'

db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QODBC')
db.setDatabaseName(f'Driver={{SQL SERVER}}; Server={SERVER}; Database={DATABASE}; UID={USERNAME}; PWD={PASSWORD}')
db.open()

def displayData(sqlStatement):
    print('processing query...')
    qry = QSqlQuery(db)
    qry.prepare(sqlStatement)
    qry.exec()

    model = QSqlQueryModel()
    model.setQuery(qry)

    view = QTableView()
    view.setModel(model)
    return view

if __name__ =='__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    SQL_STATEMENT = 'SELECT top 5 * FROM insightAccounts.dbo.insightAccount'
    dataView = displayData(SQL_STATEMENT)
    dataView.show()
    app.exit()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here is the output:

```
processing query...
QSqlQuery::prepare: database not open
"QODBCResult::exec: No statement handle available"      Error: ""
```

Comment: Have you installed the driver for that database? For more information read https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html#qodbc, what is the output of `db.open()`

Comment: You don't need to specify the port in your connection string if it's the default (1433). If you need to use a non-standard port then the separator in your SERVER variable should be a comma instead of a colon ('192.19.45.11,1433').

Comment: it's working now, thanks  @Gary Hughes